# Codewars: Make a spiral

Tags: python, algorithm

Link to full problem description: https://www.codewars.com/kata/534e01fbbb17187c7e0000c6

My code:

```
def spiralize(size):
    def get_change_values():
        change_x = 0
        change_y = 0
        if direction == 'right':
            change_x = 1
        elif direction == 'left':
            change_x = -1
        elif direction == 'down':
            change_y = 1
        elif direction == 'up':
            change_y = -1
        return change_x, change_y

    def check_collision():
        if 0 <= y + change_y * 2 < size and 0 <= x + change_x * 2 < size:
            if direction in ('right', 'left'):
                if spiral[y][x + change_x * 2]:
                    return True
            elif direction in ('down', 'up'):
                if spiral[y + change_y * 2][x]:
                    return True
        return False

    spiral = [[0 for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
    directions = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'up']
    x = y = 0
    change_directions = 0
    while change_directions < size:
        direction = directions[change_directions % 4]
        change_x, change_y = get_change_values()
        while 0 <= y + change_y < size and 0 <= x + change_x < size:
            spiral[y][x] = 1
            if check_collision():
                break
            y += change_y
            x += change_x
        change_directions += 1
    return spiral
```

The basic idea of what my algortihm is trying to do here:

- Initialize a matrix of 0s of the given size
- Starting from the top left and heading towards the right, go through each element and change it to '1' until it can no longer move in that direction
- Once it can no longer move in a given direction, change the direction based on the order right -> down -> left -> up
- Repeat until spiral is complete (until size-1 changes of direction have been made)

The main advice I'm looking for here is how to better structure this code to make it more readable and understandable to the average viewer. Granted, if there are any glaring performance optimizations that can be made to improve this code, I'd be more than willing to hear those out as well. But again, I'm mostly looking for advice on how to make this code cleaner in general. I'm not exactly a new programmer per se, but the concept of 'clean code' is still something I very much struggle with.

Comment: Please embed the problem description in the body of the question. Links can be broken.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll keep that in mind next time I post. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing your algorithm we can make your code simpler in a few places. I'd say the algorithm is quite sensible, I would've chosen the same approach.

---

**Comments and docstrings**

Providing some comments here and there and explaining the general algorithmic approach in a docstring would be good start for increasing readability. In particular, it's not intuitively obvious why `while change_directions < size:`
is the correct approach.

---

**Nested functions**

I find nested functions to be relatively hard to read. Especially when they start using variables from the outer scope (the outer function), thereby mixing namespaces. Personally, I generally try to avoid them. In the case of `check_collision` I'd say it might improve readability as it reduces the maximum indentation level. That's generally a good thing, since every indentation level is another layer of context to keep track of.

---

**get_change_values()**

We can easily get rid of this function by taking a closer look at the underlying logic. We don't actually need to pass around `direction` strings, since we always follow the same pattern `RIGHT -> DOWN -> LEFT -> UP -> RIGHT -> ...`. The [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module from the standard library provides [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which basically provides an endless iterator for a given iterable (example from the docs: `cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...`). So we might want to `cycle(['right', 'down', 'left', 'up'])`. But since we only need the strings to get the corresponding `change_x, change_y` values, we can replace them by those values directly:

```
directions = cycle(((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)))
```

We now replace

```
direction = directions[change_directions % 4]
change_x, change_y = get_change_values()
```

by

```
change_x, change_y = next(directions)
```

and get rid of `get_change_values()`.

---

**`0 <= variable < limit`**

Conditions that follow the pattern `0 <= variable < limit` **can** be replaced by `variable in range(limit)`. I personally find this to be more readable, but it's not always preferable and up to personal preference.

---

**check_collision()**

This function can be simplified to the point where we could directly put it into our nested `while` loop. This is a valid option here. But as mentioned above you might want to keep it in a seperate function to reduce the maximum indentation level.

We don't actually need to check for the direction:

```
if direction in ('right', 'left'):
    if spiral[y][x + change_x * 2]:
        return True
elif direction in ('down', 'up'):
    if spiral[y + change_y * 2][x]:
        return True
```

if we simply check

```
if spiral[y + change_y * 2][x + change_x * 2] == 1:
    return True
```

We can also directly `return`:

```
def check_collision() -> bool:
    if y + change_y * 2 in range(size) and x + change_x * 2 in range(size):
        return spiral[y + change_y * 2][x + change_x * 2] == 1
    
    return False
```

I find exit conditions to generally improve code readability as well. They're usually closer to the reader's thought process (*"If the step is out of bounds there's no collision, so we don't need to check anything else. Otherwise check if the step leads to a 1."*):

```
def check_collision() -> bool:
    if y + change_y * 2 not in range(size) or x + change_x * 2 not in range(size):
        return False
    
    return spiral[y + change_y * 2][x + change_x * 2] == 1
```

Both options are already pretty clean. I personally prefer this branchless approach:

```
def check_collision() -> bool:
    step_inside_bounds = y + change_y * 2 in range(size) and x + change_x * 2 in range(size)
    return step_inside_bounds and spiral[y + change_y * 2][x + change_x * 2] == 1
```

This works because `and` is evaluated lazily, so if `step_inside_bounds is False`, the rest of the condition is not evaluated.

---

**`spiral` initialization**

Instead of

```
spiral = [[0 for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
```

we can initialize `spiral` like this

```
spiral = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
```

This again is just another way to do things, and I wouldn't say it's definitely better for multi-dimensional lists. For one-dimensional lists, I would prefer the suggested syntax. Compare these examples:

```
my_list = [0 for _ in range(my_length)]
my_list = [0] * my_length
```

---

**Complete code**

I renamed `change_directions` to `direction_changes` and `check_collision` to `collision_in_two_steps`. I also added type hints ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)).

```
from itertools import cycle


def spiralize(size: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    def collision_in_two_steps() -> bool:
        step_inside_bounds = y + change_y * 2 in range(size) and x + change_x * 2 in range(size)
        return step_inside_bounds and spiral[y + change_y * 2][x + change_x * 2] == 1

    directions = cycle(((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)))

    spiral = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
    x, y = 0, 0
    direction_changes = 0

    while direction_changes < size:
        change_x, change_y = next(directions)

        while y + change_y in range(size) and x + change_x in range(size):
            spiral[y][x] = 1

            if collision_in_two_steps():
                break

            y += change_y
            x += change_x

        direction_changes += 1

    return spiral
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think your answer more directly answered my original question, so I'm giving the accepted solution to you

Answer (score 2):

Your current implementation is not too hard to follow and you already have some
good suggestions in another review. Here I'll try to build on those ideas and
speak more directly to your deeper question: **how does one get better at
writing cleaner, more readable, more intuitive code**.

One secret is to focus on the data. This principle has been famously
articulated many times, by the likes of Fred Brooks, Eric Raymond, Linus
Torvaldis, and Rob Pike. The latter, for example, lists the following in his [5
Rules of Programming](https://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Eadnan/pike.html):

> Rule 5. Data dominates. If you've chosen the right data structures and
> organized things well, the algorithms will almost always be
> self-evident. Data structures, not algorithms, are central to
> programming.

Start with a simple example that has already been noted. The
`get_change_values()` function is currently all algorithm. But it can be
expressed directly as data: for example, a collection of tuples expressing the
row/col shifts. Such data is immediately intuitive. In your specific case,
wrapping that collection in `itertools.cycle()` is basically a super-powered
type of data. Even though there is code lurking behind the collection, you
don't need to think about the details. From your perspective, its just an
endless collection.

A second technique that I have found useful is to avoid the temptation to move
to computer-sciencey implementation too early. I have learned this lesson the
hard way many times. Indeed, I sort of learned it trying to write this review.
I had an initial idea and jumped too soon to coding details. I struggled
through some bugs and ended up with code similar in spirit to the review you
already have -- which is a good one! On my second attempt I ignored coding
details and just tried to express the algorithm in intuitive terms.
When doing this, don't fret too much over precise implementation details.
Here's the sketch I started with. I didn't yet know what those wished-for
functions would have to do, but at a high level this seemed both correct
and directly understandable:

```python
grid = [... zeroes ...]
loc = (0, 0)

while True:
    mark_current_location(...)
    newloc = next_location(...)
    if not newloc:
        turn(...)
        newloc = next_location(...)
    if newloc:
        loc = newloc
    else:
        break

return grid
```

As you convert the plan into actual code, sometimes adjustments
occur (and sometimes you discover your plan has flaws). In this
case, the plan worked well in the sense that I was able to convert
the sketch into working code without any real hang-ups.

Another technique for code readability is to keep top-level code simple by
delegating simple algorithmic details to one or more utility functions. These
grid problems are famous for annoyances regarding out-of-bounds checks. Never
clutter up your main algorithm with tedium like that. From the outset, I expected
to write a function that would take a grid, row, and column and return either
the cell value or `None`.

Yet another technique is to invest more time in code comments. This does not
necessarily mean writing lots of comment text, and certainly the comments
shouldn't repeat every detail of the code. Rather, they should play an
organizational role, acting as major sign posts or dividers, and they should
try to express goals, intent, strategy, and so forth. Well done comments create
an overarching narrative to help the reader (usually your future self) grasp
the details in the code more readily.

Finally -- and this is more controversial -- use the shortest variable names
you can without sacrificing readability. That's inherently a balancing act:
longer names are more specific and more precise, but they can become visually
heavy, weighing down the code and imposing a tax on the reader's attention.
Within local contexts, it's often possible to get away with very short names,
provided that those names have some intuition behind them and enough
surrounding information to make them clear. Consider the first few lines of the
implementation I ended up with. At interface points (e.g., a function signature),
one often wants more specific names, like `size`. But within the function, and
following a code comment that has the phrase "row/col location", the compact
variables of `r` and `c` work perfectly fine. And that naming convention
becomes the basis for other variable names used elsewhere in the code: `dr` and
`dc` for movements (following the mathematical convention for change values)
and `nr` and `nc` for new-row/new-col. In the abstract, those names might seem
too cryptic. But in context, they are clear. For example, the latter two are
first introduced as `nr, nc = next_location(...)`. Naming is always a difficult
balancing act, but readable code pays a lot of attention to names, naming
conventions, and context.

```
def spiralize(size):
    # Setup empty grid and mark the current row/col location.
    grid = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
    r, c = (0, 0)
```

Note that this code gives different answers than yours (and the other review)
for grids sized 1, 2, and 3. The original problem excludes sizes below 5, but
that restriction seems unnecessary to me. At least the way I understand the
essence of this problem, the small spirals generated by this code make more
sense to me.

```python
from itertools import cycle

def spiralize(size):
    # Setup empty grid and mark the current row/col location.
    grid = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
    r, c = (0, 0)
    if not grid:
        return grid

    # Directions of travel (right, down, left, up).
    directions = ((0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0))
    moves = cycle(directions)
    move = next(moves)

    while True:
        # Mark current location.
        grid[r][c] = 1

        # Advance to the next row/col location.
        # If that fails, turn and try again.
        nr, nc = next_location(grid, r, c, move, directions)
        if nr is None:
            move = next(moves)
            nr, nc = next_location(grid, r, c, move, directions)

        # Halt or advance.
        if nr is None:
            break
        else:
            r, c = (nr, nc)

    return grid

def next_location(grid, r, c, move, directions):
    # Get new row/col from the move.
    dr, dc = move
    nr, nc = (r + dr, c + dc)

    # Generator expression to get cells surrounding
    # the new location, other than the current location.
    new_neighbors = (
        get(grid, nr + dr, nc + dc)
        for dr, dc in directions
        if not (nr + dr == r and nc + dc == c)
    )

    # Return:
    # - Fail: new location outside grid.
    # - Fail: new location touches existing part of snake.
    # - Success.
    return (
        (None, None) if get(grid, nr, nc) is None else
        (None, None) if any(new_neighbors) else
        (nr, nc)
    )

def get(grid, r, c):
    try:
        if r >= 0 and c >= 0:
            return grid[r][c]
        else:
            return None
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: +1 for comprehensively outlining your thought process, that's something I often struggle with. Is there a particular reason for checking `if r >= 0 and c >= 0` in `get(...)`? Wouldn't catching the `IndexError` suffice?

Comment: @riskypenguin In a generic `get()` one wouldn't want the checks. But in this specific problem, we want to disallow negative indexes (eg, when `r` is 0 and `dr` is -1).

Comment: Ah of course, for a moment I completely forgot that negative indexing is valid in Python and thought it would just throw an `IndexError`.

Comment: @FMc Thanks for the response! I appreciate the additional detail of your answer, it has definitely given me a lot to think about and consider. Though, I do wanna ask 1 thing out of curiosity. People have generally told me that having functions with many parameters (say 5 and up) is considered a bad thing, hence why I opted to use nested functions in my original solution. How valid do you think this rule of thumb is?

Comment: @dettolas It's not a bad rule of thumb, but it's not one I've ever spent much time worrying about. If the N of args for a function is so large that I find it a hassle to use, I don't conclude that I should stop using functions or that I should move them to inner functions (I rarely do the latter). Rather I consider whether my functions could be decomposed further, whether the arguments could be packaged up into useful data-bundles/objects, or whether the functions could be put into a meaningful class to reduce argument passing. But reducing function args is never a driving goal by itself.